# Using data member in lambda capture list inside a member function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lambda, c++11

The following code compiles with gcc 4.5.1 but not with VS2010 SP1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
 
using namespace std;
class puzzle
{
    vector<vector<int>> grid;
    map<int,set<int>> groups;
public:
    int member_function();
};
 
int puzzle::member_function()
{
    int i;
    for_each(groups.cbegin(), groups.cend(), [grid, &i](pair<int,set<int>> group) {
        i++;
        cout << i << endl;
    });
}
```

This is the error:

```
error C3480: 'puzzle::grid': a lambda capture variable must be from an enclosing function scope
warning C4573: the usage of 'puzzle::grid' requires the compiler to capture 'this' but the current default capture mode does not allow it
```

1. Which compiler is right?
2. How can I use data members inside a lambda in VS2010?

Comment: Note: It should be `pair<const int, set<int> >`, that's the actual pair-type of a map. It should possibly also be a reference-to-const.

Comment: Related; very helpful: https://thispointer.com/c11-lambda-how-to-capture-member-variables-inside-lambda-function/

Comment: use [&] to capture by reference.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

I believe VS2010 to be right this time, and I'd check if I had the standard handy, but currently I don't.

Now, it's exactly like the error message says: You can't capture stuff outside of the enclosing scope of the lambda.<sup>†</sup> `grid` is not in the enclosing scope, but `this` is (every access to `grid` actually happens as `this->grid` in member functions). For your usecase, capturing `this` works, since you'll use it right away and you don't want to copy the `grid`

```
auto lambda = [this](){ std::cout << grid[0][0] << "\n"; }
```

If however, you want to store the grid and copy it for later access, where your `puzzle` object might already be destroyed, you'll need to make an intermediate, local copy:

```
vector<vector<int> > tmp(grid);
auto lambda = [tmp](){}; // capture the local copy per copy
```

---

† I'm simplifying - Google for "reaching scope" or see §5.1.2 for all the gory details.

Comment: It seems quite limited to me. I don't understand why a compiler would need to prevent such a thing. It works well with bind, although the syntax is horrible with the ostream left shift operator.

Comment: Could `tmp` be a `const &` to `grid` to cut down on copying? We still want at least one copy, the copy into the lambda (`[tmp]`), but no need for a second copy.

Comment: The solution might make an unnecessary extra copy of `grid` though it probably gets optimized out.  Shorter and better is:  `auto& tmp = grid;` etc.

Comment: If you have C++14 available, you could do `[grid = grid](){ std::cout << grid[0][0] << "\n"; }` to avoid the extra copy

Comment: It seems to be fixed in gcc 4.9 ( and gcc 5.4 for that matter) `error: capture of non-variable ‘puzzle::grid’`

Answer (score 212):

### Summary of the alternatives:

capture `this`:

```
auto lambda = [this](){};
```

use a local reference to the member:

```
auto& tmp = grid;
auto lambda = [ tmp](){}; // capture grid by (a single) copy
auto lambda = [&tmp](){}; // capture grid by ref
```

**C++14:**

```
auto lambda = [ grid = grid](){}; // capture grid by copy
auto lambda = [&grid = grid](){}; // capture grid by ref
```

example: https://godbolt.org/g/dEKVGD

Comment: Interesting that only explicit use of the capture with initializer syntax works for this (i.e. in C++14 just doing `[&grid]` still doesn't work). Very glad to know this!

Comment: Good summary. I find the C++14 syntax very convenient

Comment: Note that the variable name can be anything: `auto lambda = [&anyName = grid](){};`

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. I think it could be improved with a brief explanation on the differences between the options. Has the C++14 notation performance differences or any other advantage from the "capture this" option?

Comment: If you use references it generates the same code: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/58TTjPqob

It's more about limiting the amount of state you can access I guess, or to make it more explicit. Of course when copying objects it's much better to only copy parts of this instead of the whole *this.

Answer (score 23):

I believe, you need to capture `this`.

Comment: This is correct, it will capture the this-pointer and you can still just refer to `grid` directly. Problem being, what if you want to copy the grid? This won't allow you to do that.

Comment: You can, but only in a roundabout way: You have to make a local copy, and capture *that* in the lambda. That's just the rule with lambdas, you can't capture stiff outside of the enclosing scope.

Comment: Sure you can copy. I meant you can't copy-capture it, of course.

Comment: What I described does a copy capture, through the intermediate local copy - see my answer. Aside from that, I don't know any way to copy capture a member variable.

Comment: Sure, it does copy capture, but not the member. It involves two copies unless compiler is smarter than usual, I'd guess.

Comment: We can get pedantic that this can be seen as a copy capture of the member, but lets just say that we both mean the same thing, ok? :)

Comment: I think we both mean the same thing for quite a while now :)

Comment: For "capturing that", see my answer here, which is in an entirely different answer and context but applies just as well here (just ignore the async part): https://stackoverflow.com/a/42193934/1599699

Answer (score 16):

An alternate method that limits the scope of the lambda rather than giving it access to the whole `this` is to pass in a local reference to the member variable, e.g.

```
auto& localGrid = grid;
int i;
for_each(groups.cbegin(),groups.cend(),[localGrid,&i](pair<int,set<int>> group){
            i++;
            cout<<i<<endl;
   });
```

Comment: I love your idea: **using a fake reference variable and pass it to capture list** :)