# Class and std::async on class member in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm try to write a class member which calls another class member multiple times in parallel.

I wrote a simple example of the problem and can't even get to compile this. What am I doing wrong with calling std::async? I guess the problem would be with how I'm passing the the function.

```
#include <vector>
#include <future>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    int a,b;
public: 
    A(int i=1, int j=2){ a=i; b=j;} 

    std::pair<int,int> do_rand_stf(int x,int y)
    {
        std::pair<int,int> ret(x+a,y+b);
        return ret;
    }

    void run()
    {
        std::vector<std::future<std::pair<int,int>>> ran;
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                auto hand=async(launch::async,do_rand_stf,i,j);
                ran.push_back(hand);    
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<ran.size();i++)
        {
            pair<int,int> ttt=ran[i].get();
            cout << ttt.first << ttt.second << endl;
        } 
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.run();
}
```

compilation:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread main.cpp
```

Comment: Pass `*this` as the third parameter to `async`.

Comment: If you get errors in compilation or linking, it would be a good idea to include those errors in the question, preferably verbatim.

Comment: You don't need to use pthread anymore with C++11 :) Thats is one of the biggest addition in C++11 ( threading ). async() is implicit thread if asynchronous launch and explicit threading is also there in the language itself.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`do_rand_stf` is a non-static member function and thus cannot be called without a class instance (the implicit `this` parameter.) Luckily, `std::async` handles its parameters like `std::bind`, and `bind` in turn can use `std::mem_fn` to turn a member function pointer into a functor that takes an explicit `this` parameter, so all you need to do is to pass `this` to the `std::async` invocation and use valid member function pointer syntax when passing the `do_rand_stf`:

```
auto hand=async(launch::async,&A::do_rand_stf,this,i,j);
```

There are other problems in the code, though. First off, you use `std::cout` and `std::endl` without `#include`ing `<iostream>`. More seriously, `std::future` is not copyable, only movable, so you cannot `push_back` the named object `hand` without using `std::move`. Alternatively, just pass the `async` result to `push_back` directly:

```
ran.push_back(async(launch::async,&A::do_rand_stf,this,i,j));
```

Comment: Do you have any references that `std::async` uses `std::bind` internally? Because I can't find any.

Comment: @Rakete1111 It's not defined in terms of `std::bind`, directly, but does the same thing. Since C++17 both are defined in terms of `std::invoke`. Before that, they were defined in terms of the non-reified INVOKE expression. I edited the phrasing a bit.

Comment: Use `emplace_back` with `std::move`

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the `this` pointer to a new thread:

```
async([this]()
{
    Function(this);
});
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what makes `this` and `that` different? The inner thread's `this` is the same like outer thread's `this`, except for there should be no inner thread `this` at all, unless captured? Sounds more like javascript trick…

Comment: `this_thread::get_id()` is a way to see the thread id difference, not `this`. Which will not be available in lambda if you don't capture it at all. Like here — http://ideone.com/uWNs4p — you need to capture `this` explicitly. And if you do, it's no different than outside of lambda — http://ideone.com/YuPKf9

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker You appear to be correct, at least with gcc: http://ideone.com/G9icfv I was using Visual Studio; it's very possible it works differently with that.

Comment: I hope you're mistaken about Visual Studio too, but one can't be sure… I don't have one around to quickly test it.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Same outcome in Visual Studio 2017 c++. Deleted my comment; I stand corrected. I suppose then that the only usage for `that` would be to pass to another object using that variable name.

Comment: Also revised my answer. For those trying to understand what the heck we're talking about, see the edit.