# Can I get the return with future in the thread?

Tags: c++, c++17

```
int returnKillProcesses = 0;
std::thread { 
    []() {
       auto future = std::async(ThreadKillProcess);
       returnKillProcesses = future.get();
    }
}.detach();
```

I want to define the return of the running function to the returnKillProcess parameter. How can I do it?

And I have one more question.
How can I run a function in another class with std::async?
Example:

```
std::thread { 
    []() {
       auto future = std::async( exampleClass->exampleFunction ); // Here
       returnKillProcesses = future.get();
    }
}.detach();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to define the return of the running function to the returnKillProcess parameter. How can I do it?

Use the future as you already did:

```cpp
std::future<int> worker = std::async(&Foo::killProcess, &foo);
returnKillProcess = worker.get();
```

I used a class `Foo`, which holds a public function `killProcess` (it returns 1 in this example). If you want to use a function defined in a class make this function static or add a valid pointer to a reference to an instance of this class (see [Class and std::async on class member in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758414/class-and-stdasync-on-class-member-in-c/11758662)). The reason you may not see returnKillProcess changing is that you are detaching your thread. The moment you create the new thread your main thread will continue to execute its instructions. Now it can happen that your main thread will be finished before the newly created thread has changed the value of `returnKillProcesses`. To prevent this don't [detach](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/detach/) your thread and use `join` to wait in your main thread before you are reading the value until the created thread has finished. Therefore your code could look something like that:

```cpp
class Foo {

public:
    int killProcess() {
        return 1;
    }
};

int main() {

    int returnKillProcess = 0;
    Foo foo;

    std::thread workerThread(
        [&]() {
            std::future<int> worker = std::async(&Foo::killProcess, &foo);
            returnKillProcess = worker.get();
        }
    );

    workerThread.join();
       
    std::cout << returnKillProcess << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

And please note that [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) can be called with a launch policy:

> If the async flag is set (i.e. (policy & std::launch::async) != 0), then async executes the callable object f on a new thread of execution (with all thread-locals initialized) as if spawned by std::thread(std::forward(f), std::forward(args)...), except that if the function f returns a value or throws an exception, it is stored in the shared state accessible through the std::future that async returns to the caller.

So your code would become:

```cpp
int returnKillProcess = 0;
Foo foo;

std::future<int> worker = std::async(std::launch::async, &Foo::killProcess, &foo);
returnKillProcess = worker.get();
       
std::cout << returnKillProcess << "\n";
```

You may want to look at [mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) as well.