# How can I sort an array using a custom comparator?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl, comparator

When I call my `build` function from my code below, I get the following compile errors:

```
error C3867: 'SuffixArray::cmp': function call missing argument list; use '&SuffixArray::cmp' to create a pointer to member
error C2780: 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
```

This is my code:

```
class A{
private:
    std::string text;
    std::vector<int> array;

    bool cmp(int a, int b) {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(text.begin() + a, text.end(),
                                            text.begin() + b, text.end());
    }

    void build(const std::string &str, std::vector<int> &vec) {

        // Some vector values actions.

        std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp);
    }
};
```

What's wrong here? I'm using the Visual C++ compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comparison function `A::cmp` is a non-static member of `A`. Thus, it takes three arguments: in addition to the two arguments explicitly declared, it also takes a pointer to `A` to become the implicitly available `this`. It also has a different type than normal function pointers: `bool (A::)(int, int)` which decays into `bool (A::*)(int, int)` when being passed by value.

You could `std::bind()` your function to a suitable object, however:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
          std::bind(&A::cmp, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
```

Comment: I was going to suggest him to make it a static function... your advice is a lot more complete.

Comment: @Jekyll: Suggesting a `static` member was my first idea, too, but the code actually uses `A::text` in the `A::cmp()` function, i.e., the object is actually needed. That is, making the function `static` wouldn't solve the problem!

Comment: since the bind function was only introduced in c++11 I wonder how could you deal with it before the new standard?(I don't really need it, just curious)

Comment: @SAD: well, you could use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/)'s `bind()` or write a custom function object class, e.g.: `struct cmp { std::string const* name; cmp(std::string const* name): name(name) {} bool operator()(int a, int a) const { return std::lexicographical_compare(...); } };`

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @DietmarKühl explains perfectly, why your code does not compile.
But since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), you can also use a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of defining a comparison function or making it static:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class A{
private:
    std::string text;
    std::vector<int> array;

    void build(const std::string &str, std::vector<int> &vec) {

        // Some vector values actions.

        std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [this](int a, int b) {
            return std::lexicographical_compare(text.begin() + a, text.end(),
                                                text.begin() + b, text.end());
        });
    }
};
```

I order to be able to access the class member `text` in the lambda expression, I captured the `this` pointer.
However, if you want an alternative to capturing `this`, please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42029220/2675154).