# Is there a way to avoid having global variable to implement qsort

Tags: c++, qsort

I have a project with a single `.h` file and multiple `.cpp` files. The header file contains a namespace `UF` (abbreviation for **u**seful **f**unctions) that currently implements sorting.

This is done by having a comparator defined in `UF.cpp` thus:

```
    int compar_int_asc(const void *a, const void *b)
    {
        int aa = *((int *)a), bb = *((int *)b);
        if (base_arr_int[aa] < base_arr_int[bb])
            return -1;
        if (base_arr_int[aa] == base_arr_int[bb])
            return 0;
        if (base_arr_int[aa] > base_arr_int[bb])
            return 1;
    }
```

At present, the base array `base_arr_int` that needs to be accessed by `qsort` and the comparator function above is declared in `main.cpp` and externed in `UF.cpp`.

I access `qsort` within a different class, `SEP` as follows. Firstly, in `SEP.cpp`, I extern `base_arr_int`. Then, if `ratios[100]` is an integer array that is native and local to `SEP`, I do the following within `SEP.cpp`.

```
base_arr_int = ratios;
qsort(indices, 100, sizeof(int), UF::compar_int_asc);
```

Is this the best way of implementing qsort with multiple classes?

In particular, I would like to avoid using global variables defined in `main.cpp` as much as possible. Is there any alternative design?

Comment: Would you like to consider `std::sort` instead of `qsort`?

Comment: @NickyC Yes, if it helps avoid global variables in main.cpp. Also, I don't sort the `ratios` array itself, but sort the `indices` so that `ratios[indices[0]]` is the smallest element, `ratios[indices[1]]`the next smallest and so on. Does `std::sort` help with that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the global variable is to figuratively place the array inside the custom comparator. To eliminate the global variable, let's literally put `ratio` into the custom comparator. To do so, the custom comparator cannot be an ordinary function or function pointer. It needs to be a **function object**. And `std::sort` supports that.

Let's do it step by step.

---

So, you have an array that stores things.

```
int ratio[5] = {300, 400, 200, 500, 100};
```

But you don't want to sort it directly. You create an array of indices which actually gets sorted.

```
int index[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

The goal is to sort `index`. So let's write:

```
std::sort(index, index + 5);
```

But it is not what you want yet. You also need to pass a custom comparator `index_comp` because the default less-than comparator is not what you need.

```
std::sort(index, index + 5, index_comp);
```

The rest of the work is how to write `index_comp`. It is actually quite simple: lambda expression

```
auto index_comp = [&ratio](int index_left, int index_right) { return ratio[index_left] < ratio[index_right]; };
```

This lambda expression captures the array `ratio` by reference (`[&ratio]`). It has a parameter list taking two indices. The body compares the two actual objects in `ratio`.

If you prefer the old school way, the lambda expression is just syntax sugar for the following:

```
class Compiler_Generated_Name
{
private:
    int (&ratio)[5];

public:
    Compiler_Generated_Name(int (&ratio_)[5]) : ratio(ratio_) {}

    bool operator()(int index_left, int index_right)
    {
        return ratio[index_left] < ratio[index_right];
    }
};

Compiler_Generated_Name index_comp(ratio);
```

The whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int ratio[5] = {300, 400, 200, 500, 100};
    int index[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    
    auto index_comp = [&ratio](int index_left, int index_right) { return ratio[index_left] < ratio[index_right]; };
    
    std::sort(index, index + 5, index_comp);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout << ratio[index[i]] << ' ';
}
```

Comment: I am having some trouble implementing this. In my `SEP` class, I have `ratio` declared as `int *ratio`. I then dynamically new this in order to populate the values. Then, I have `std::sort(indexofarray, indexofarray + 5, [&ratio](int index_left, int index_right) { return ratio[index_left] < ratio[index_right]; });` within a member function of `SEP` but this gives me the following error: `member "SEP::ratio" is not a variable`

Comment: In the case of member variable, you can capture the `this` pointer, as in `[this](int index_left, int index_right) { ... };` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895879