# How to call this Lambda function in C++

Tags: c++, lambda

I was writing a lambda function inside a **protected void** function of this class

```
class Tetris: protected TetrisArea<true>
{
public:
    Tetris(unsigned rx) : TetrisArea(rx), seq(),hiscore(0),hudtimer(0) {}
    virtual ~Tetris() { }

protected:
    // These variables should be local to GameLoop(),
    // but because of coroutines, they must be stored
    // in a persistent wrapper instead. Such persistent
    // wrapper is provided by the game object itself.
    Piece seq[4];
```

The lambda function,

```
auto fx = [&seq]() {  seq[0].x=4;       seq[0].y=-1;
                        seq[1].x=Width;   seq[1].y=Height-4;
                        seq[2].x=Width+4; seq[2].y=Height-4; };
```

So here's the problem. I got these errors:

```
 error: capture of non-variable 'Tetris::seq' 
         auto fx = [&seq]() {  seq[0].x=4;       seq[0].y=-1;
 error: 'this' was not captured for this lambda function
     auto fx = [&seq]() {  seq[0].x=4;       seq[0].y=-1;
```

.. and also for subsequent reference of seq[n] in the function.

I tried to type the code directly in the **protected void** function but although it compiles, it doesn't seem to work normally as the program is from the Youtube channel Bisqwit in his Tetris Dos game.

Comment: A duplicate indeed, my bad for not searching for related questions!

Comment: However hoped to be useful for others in the near future

Comment: you should also post a [mcve]. There is no protected method in that code. I guess you left out that part

Answer (score 2):

As it reads, you try to capture an object's member without capturing the object itself. Change `[&seq]` into `[this]` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks it worked anyway! Really appreciated!

Comment: If you can use C++14, there's a new way using initialized lambda capture expressions: `auto fx = [&ref = seq]() { ref[0].x=4; etc. }`

Comment: Actually, it can say `[&seq = seq]` and then proceed as the original version. Such a simple name reuse is applied in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42029220/1537925) to the linked question.