# C++ lambda - capture static member variable

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a lambda function inside a *static* class method, like so:

```
void
MyClass::foo() {
  auto my_lambda = [](int arg) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Where `foo` is a static method of `MyClass`. Now, inside `my_lambda` I want to reference another static method `bar` of `MyClass`. How can I do this? I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895879/using-member-variable-in-lambda-capture-list-inside-a-member-function) but it seems like this only works for non static methods, since static methods cannot reference `this`?

Comment: How can I do this? Just like you would anywhere else.  `ClassName::StaticFunctionName(Parameters);`

Comment: What did you actually try? Simply calling `bar` works as expected since it's a static method. No need to capture anything.

Comment: title doesn't match content.. static method is a global function, static variable is a little different, but both are available through name?

Comment: You don't need `this` to accesses a static method. So simply capture the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my naive take on it - but I may have misunderstood the question.

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
private:
    static int variable;                                // just some common data

public:
    static void another(int dest) {                     // receiver
        std::cout << "I'm alive: " << dest << "\n"; 
    }
    static void foo();
};

int MyClass::variable = 4;                              // 

void MyClass::foo() {
    auto my_lambda = [](int arg) {
        another(arg + variable);                        // reference another static method
    };
    my_lambda(123);
}

int main() {
    MyClass apa;

    apa.foo();
}
```

```
I'm alive: 127
```