# Invalid use of this

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is my echelleetserpent.hpp :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

#ifndef ECHELLE
#define ECHELLE

struct Player{
    int position;
    int n_step;
    Player(): position(0), n_step(0) {};
};

class SnakesAndLadders{
    private:
        int n_players;
        int n_board;
        std::vector<Player> players;
        std::vector<int> board;
    public:
        int roll_die(std::mt19937 &) const;
        bool one_step(std::mt19937 & G, int j);
        int game(std::mt19937);
};



#endif
```

And my echelleetserpent.cpp

```
#include "echelleetserpent.hpp"
#include <algorithm>

int SnakesAndLadders::roll_die(std::mt19937 & gen) const {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> U(1,6);
    int dice = U(gen);
    return dice;
}

bool SnakesAndLadders::one_step(std::mt19937 & G, int j) {
    int dice = roll_die(G);
    std::cout << "Le résultat du dé est : " << dice << std::endl;
    players[j].n_step++;
    players[j].position+=dice;
    return (players[j].position >= n_board) ? true : false;
}

int SnakesAndLadders::game(std::mt19937 G) {
    while (std::any_of(players.begin(), players.end(), [n_board](Player p) {return p.position < n_board;})) {
        for(int i=0; i<n_players; i++) {
            this->one_step(G,i);
        }
    }
    return std::min_element(this->players.begin(), this->players.end(), [n_board](Player p1, Player p2) {
        if(p1.position>=n_board and p2.position >= n_board) { return p1.position < p2.position; } else { return false; }});
}
```

And i get the following error :

```
echelleetserpent.cpp: In member function ‘int SnakesAndLadders::game(std::mt19937)’:
echelleetserpent.cpp:60:54: error: capture of non-variable ‘SnakesAndLadders::n_board’ 
  while (std::any_of(players.begin(), players.end(), [n_board](Player p) {return p.position < n_board;})) {
                                                      ^~~~~~~
In file included from echelleetserpent.cpp:1:0:
echelleetserpent.hpp:18:7: note: ‘int SnakesAndLadders::n_board’ declared here
   int n_board;
       ^~~~~~~
echelleetserpent.cpp: In lambda function:
echelleetserpent.cpp:60:94: error: ‘this’ was not captured for this lambda function
 rs.begin(), players.end(), [n_board](Player p) {return p.position < n_board;})) {
                                                                     ^~~~~~~
echelleetserpent.cpp:60:94: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘SnakesAndLadders::n_board’
In file included from echelleetserpent.cpp:1:0:
echelleetserpent.hpp:18:7: note: declared here
   int n_board;
       ^~~~~~~
echelleetserpent.cpp: In member function ‘int SnakesAndLadders::game(std::mt19937)’:
echelleetserpent.cpp:65:71: error: capture of non-variable ‘SnakesAndLadders::n_board’ 
 eturn std::min_element(this->players.begin(), this->players.end(), [n_board](Player p1, Player p2) {
                                                                     ^~~~~~~
In file included from echelleetserpent.cpp:1:0:
echelleetserpent.hpp:18:7: note: ‘int SnakesAndLadders::n_board’ declared here
   int n_board;
       ^~~~~~~
echelleetserpent.cpp: In lambda function:
echelleetserpent.cpp:66:19: error: ‘this’ was not captured for this lambda function
   if(p1.position>=n_board and p2.position >= n_board) { return p1.position < p2.position; } else { return false; }});
                   ^~~~~~~
echelleetserpent.cpp:66:19: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘SnakesAndLadders::n_board’
In file included from echelleetserpent.cpp:1:0:
echelleetserpent.hpp:18:7: note: declared here
   int n_board;
       ^~~~~~~
echelleetserpent.cpp:66:46: error: ‘this’ was not captured for this lambda function
   if(p1.position>=n_board and p2.position >= n_board) { return p1.position < p2.position; } else { return false; }});
                                              ^~~~~~~
echelleetserpent.cpp:66:46: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘SnakesAndLadders::n_board’
In file included from echelleetserpent.cpp:1:0:
echelleetserpent.hpp:18:7: note: declared here
   int n_board;
       ^~~~~~~
echelleetserpent.cpp: In member function ‘int SnakesAndLadders::game(std::mt19937)’:
echelleetserpent.cpp:66:116: error: cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Player*, std::vector<Player> >’ to ‘int’ in return
 ion >= n_board) { return p1.position < p2.position; } else { return false; }});
```

And the error continue :

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/7/vector:60,
>                    from echelleetserpent.hpp:1,
>                    from echelleetserpent.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/7/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of ‘bool
>   __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<_Predicate>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Predicate = SnakesAndLadders::game(std::mt19937)::]’:
>   /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:120:14:   required from
>   ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__find_if(_RandomAccessIterator,
>   _RandomAccessIterator, _Predicate, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Predicate =
>   __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred
>
> > ]’ /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:161:23:   required from ‘_Iterator std::__find_if(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Predicate) [with
> >     _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred
> >     ]’ /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:3932:28:   required from ‘_IIter std::find_if(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate) [with _IIter =
> >     __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Predicate = SnakesAndLadders::game(std::mt19937)::]’ /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:526:47:   required from ‘bool
> >     std::none_of(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate) [with _IIter =
> >     __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Predicate = SnakesAndLadders::game(std::mt19937)::]’ /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:544:27:   required from ‘bool
> >     std::any_of(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate) [with _IIter =
> >     __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Predicate = SnakesAndLadders::game(std::mt19937)::]’ echelleetserpent.cpp:60:103:   required from here
> >     /usr/include/c++/7/bits/predefined_ops.h:283:11: error: void value not
> >     ignored as it ought to be   { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }

Comment: I think you want to capture "this"

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying, I captured n_board, which should be enough, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using member variable in lambda capture list inside a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895879/using-member-variable-in-lambda-capture-list-inside-a-member-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need to capture this.

```
while (std::any_of(players.begin(), players.end(), [this](Player p) {return p.position < n_board;})) {
    for(int i=0; i<n_players; i++) {
        this->one_step(G,i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Just to understand: when I capture n_player and n_board, it makes me a mistake. How come? I only need n_player and n_board in my lambda fonction