# Qt QThread stop when I need

Tags: c++, qt

```cpp
//Work.h
#ifndef WORK_H
#define WORK_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>

class Work : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
 public:
  explicit Work(QObject *parent = nullptr);

 public slots:
  void snap();
  void setStatus();

 signals:

 private:
  bool status;
};

#endif  // WORK_H


//Work.cpp
#include "Work.h"

Work::Work(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) { status = true; }

void Work::snap() {
  status = true;
  while (true) {
    if (status) {
      qDebug() << "Work thread: " << QThread::currentThreadId();
    } else {
      qDebug() << "STOP";
      break;
    }
  }
}

void Work::setStatus() { status = false; }
```

```cpp
//MainWindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QThread>

#include "Work.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
  MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
  ~MainWindow();

 private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;
  Work *work;
  QThread thread;
};
#endif  // MAINWINDOW_H


//MainWindow.cpp
#include "MainWindow.h"

#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
  ui->setupUi(this);
  work = new Work();
  work->moveToThread(&thread);
  thread.start();

  connect(ui->startButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), work, SLOT(snap()));
  connect(ui->stopButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), work, SLOT(setStatus()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
  thread.terminate();
  delete ui;
}
```

```cpp
//main.cpp
#include <QApplication>

#include "MainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  qDebug() << QThread::currentThreadId();
  w.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

I use `MainWindow` to display, `Work` to do something. And I use `work->moveToThread(&thread)`.

Click `start` button to execute `snap` function in Work, what I want to do is when I click stop button, the `snap` function output `STOP`. And I can still `start` and `stop` whenever I like.

But I fail. It seems impossible to change the status during the `while loop`. Work doesn't get the `stopButton clicked signal`. Is it because of priority?

Could anyone give me some advices?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly consider your `Work::snap` implementation...

```
void Work::snap() {
  status = true;
  while (true) {
    if (status) {
      qDebug() << "Work thread: " << QThread::currentThreadId();
    } else {
      qDebug() << "STOP";
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Once started it never yields control to the Qt event loop.  Now consider the `connect` call...

```
connect(ui->stopButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), work, SLOT(setStatus()));
```

Since `ui->stopButton` and `work` have different thread affinities this is effectively a queued connection and *requires* the receiver to have an active event loop.  Hence the call to `setStatus` will remain pending forever.

A better way to achieve your goal might be to make use of a simple atomic bool...

```
std::atomic<bool> status;
```

and change the `connect` call to modify `status` directly using a lambda (untested)...

```
connect(ui->stopButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]{ work->setStatus(); });
```

Comment: And I retry your code and there is a little errors:
`connect(ui->stopButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [work]{ work->setStatus(); });`
I change it to :`connect(ui->stopButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [this] { work->setStatus(); });`
After I change `work` to `this` ,your answer is right.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895879/using-member-variable-in-lambda-capture-list-inside-a-member-function)

Comment: @liuyulvv Indeed, my mistake.  Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it.

I add a slot and a signal in `MainWindow` and change `stop` slot.

```cpp
connect(ui->startButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::start);
connect(this, &MainWindow::startSnap, work, &Work::snap);

// start slot
void MainWindow::start() {
  thread.start();
  emit startSnap();
}

void MainWindow::stop() {
  if (thread.isRunning()) {
    thread.requestInterruption();
  }
}
```

And change the codes in `Work::snap`

```cpp
void Work::snap() {
  while (true) {
    if (QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested()) {
      qDebug() << "STOP";
      QThread::currentThread()->exit();
      return;
    } else {
      qDebug() << "Work thread: " << QThread::currentThreadId();
    }
  }
}
```

The key codes are:

- `thread.requestInterruption();`(MainWindow::stop)
- `QThread::currentThread()->exit();`(Work::snap)
- `thread.start();`(MainWindow::start)

Comment: How is this different from my own answer?  You make use of `requestInterruption` whereas I used an atomic bool to request interruption.  It should amount to the same thing.  Can you show how `MainWindow::stop` is called?  The `connect` call?

Comment: `connect(ui->stopButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::stop);`